Challenges in Debugging Flutter Web Integration Tests
I am having difficulties in debugging my integration tests for flutter web. In the beginning I have started my tests from the terminal using flutter drive with the following command:
flutter drive --target=integration_test/scenariosPage_tests.dart --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart -d chrome

Running from the terminal would make it impossible to debug in intellij. i have made a custom Run Configuration in intellij in order run it from the ide
here is the intellij run configuration
Using flutter test does not work for these kind of intergration tests.
Here is an example code for an integration test:
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  testWidgets('--- Validate something ---',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
        // write your logic here
  });
}

I’ve noticed most documentation and examples are focused on Flutter mobile. Resources specific to Flutter web integration tests seem scarce.
Any suggestions or tips on how to properly debug Flutter web integration tests would be greatly appreciated!
I tried running my integration tests for Flutter web using the flutter drive command and also through a custom IntelliJ configuration where I set the Dart entry point to the absolute path of my test file. I was expecting the breakpoints I set in the code to work as usual, pausing the execution at the defined points so I could debug the application. However, when I start the test, the breakpoints get disabled, and I can't debug as intended.
